# Summing the values from the 2nd table based on ID of the 1st table and inserting values in first table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, procedure

How to in first table where it says `UkupnaCena` insert sum value of column `Cena` where `RacunID` in first table is equal to `RacunID` in other table. For example if `RacunID` is equal to 1 in first table, I want its `UkupnaCena` to be equal to sum of all values in column `Cena` where `RacunID` is 1.

Tables:

[image]

My procedure so far:

```
Create procedure sp_RacunUpdate(
    @pRacunID int,
    @pStatusRacuna nvarchar(50),
    @pDatum nvarchar(20),
    @pOpis nvarchar(200),
    @pMesto nvarchar(50),
    @pKupacID int
)
as begin
Declare @pUkupnaCena decimal(20,2)
select @pUkupnaCena=sum(Cena) from Stavka
inner join Racun
on Racun.RacunID=Stavka.RacunID
Where Racun.RacunID=Stavka.RacunID
group by Stavka.RacunID    
begin transaction
UPDATE Racun
SET StatusRacuna=@pStatusRacuna, Datum=@pDatum, Opis=@pOpis,Mesto=@pMesto,UkupnaCena=@pUkupnaCena,KupacID=@pKupacID
WHERE RacunID=@pRacunID
IF @@ERROR <> 0
BEGIN
ROLLBACK
END
ELSE
BEGIN
COMMIT
END
END
GO
```

Comment: Your question is tagged MySQL but the code is not MySQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify the  update query to something like this

```
UPDATE Racun from Racun
SET UkupnaCena=(select sum(Cena) from Stavka s where s.RacunID= Racun.RacunID), Datum=@pDatum, Opis=@pOpis,Mesto=@pMesto,KupacID=@pKupacID 
WHERE RacunID=@pRacunID
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want a correlated subquery.  In MySQL, this would look like:

```
UPDATE Racun r
    SET StatusRacuna = @pStatusRacuna,
        Datum = @pDatum,
        Opis = @pOpis,
        Mesto = @pMesto,
        KupacID = @pKupacID,
        UkupnaCena = (SELECT SUM(s.Cena) FROM Stavka s WHERE s.RacunID = r.RacunId)
    WHERE RacunID = @pRacunID;
```

However, your code does not look like MySQL; it looks more like SQL Server.  In either database, you can do:

```
UPDATE Racun
    SET StatusRacuna = @pStatusRacuna,
        Datum = @pDatum,
        Opis = @pOpis,
        Mesto = @pMesto,
        KupacID = @pKupacID,
        UkupnaCena = (SELECT SUM(s.Cena) FROM Stavka s WHERE s.RacunID = Racun.RacunId)
    WHERE RacunID = @pRacunID;
```

The only difference here is removing the table alias in the outer query.